# Swipe JS - Display 3 Slides at a time

Tags: javascript, html, swipe

I'm using the Swipe JS for a mobile app, I want to display 3 slides at a time (well one central side, and two half slides at the side - so you can just about see the next slides on either side):

[image]

I've managed to get it so the slide layout are like this. Only issue is that if I start on 1, then 0 is on my left (great), but the last slide (6) is on the right, instead of 2.

And when I slide to the next slide, slide 0 stays there, but slide 1 just moves over the top. I want it so the entire slider moves, not just the left, centre and right.

How would I achieve this?

```
.swipe {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
}

#myWrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 620px;
}


<div id='myWrapper'>
  <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:300px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
      <div><b>0</b></div>
      <div><b>1</b></div>
      <div><b>2</b></div>
      <div><b>3</b></div>
      <div><b>4</b></div>
      <div><b>5</b></div>
      <div><b>6</b></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Old question but I've just found the answer using the API with no hacks.

The trick is to display 2 items, with a centered slides set to true.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        centeredSlides: true
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

REALLY OLD question but this worked for me:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: 1.25,
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 50,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
    });
</script>
```

This will result in two slides on either sides with the main slide centered.

Note: You can change `SlidesPerView` property based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with it, my code is definitely not the most efficient way, but it gets the job done though....

My approach is as follow:

=>z-index of any three showing slides have to be higher than other slides, and current showing slides'  z-index increases as you click "prev" or "next" button.

=>Special cases are when the index of middle slide is '0' or '6'. Say your middle slide is now '0' after clicking 'next' button six times. z-index of slide '1' and '6' will be have the same degree as slide '0', great!! but what happened when you click 'prev' button? slide '0's z-index is actually lower then slide '1'. Ergo, '0'(first) and '6'(last) targeted slides have to be treated special.

Hope this helps :)

```
//JQuery
window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
var numClick = 0;
$("#next").bind('click',function(){
    numClick += 1;
    indexSwipe = mySwipe.getPos();
    curIndex = "#index"+indexSwipe;
    preIndex = "#index"+(indexSwipe-1);
    nextIndex = "#index"+(indexSwipe+1);
    if(indexSwipe == 0){
        $(curIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index6").css("z-index",numClick);
        $(nextIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    }else if(indexSwipe == 6){
        $(curIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index5").css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index0").css("z-index",numClick);
    }else{
    $(indexSwipe).css("z-index",numClick);
    $(preIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    $(nextIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    }
});

$("#prev").bind('click',function(){
    numClick += 1;
    indexSwipe = mySwipe.getPos();
    curIndex = "#index"+indexSwipe;
    preIndex = "#index"+(indexSwipe-1);
    nextIndex = "#index"+(indexSwipe+1);
    if(indexSwipe == 0){
        $(curIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index6").css("z-index",numClick);
        $(nextIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    }else if(indexSwipe == 6){
        $(curIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index5").css("z-index",numClick);
        $("#index0").css("z-index",numClick);
    }else{
    $(indexSwipe).css("z-index",numClick);
    $(preIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    $(nextIndex).css("z-index",numClick);
    }
});


<!--HTML-->
<div style='text-align:center;padding:5px 0px;'>
<button id="prev" onclick='mySwipe.prev();return false;'>&LT;</button>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<button id="next" onclick='mySwipe.next();return false;'>&GT;</button>
</div>

<div id='myWrapper'>
  <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:300px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
      <div id="index0"><b>0</b></div>
      <div id="index1" style="z-index:1;"><b>1</b></div>
      <div id="index2"><b>2</b></div>
      <div id="index3"><b>3</b></div>
      <div id="index4"><b>4</b></div>
      <div id="index5"><b>5</b></div>
      <div id="index6"><b>6</b></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!-- /myWrapper -->

<-- .css -->
.swipe {
overflow: visible;
visibility: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap {
overflow: visible;
position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap > div {
float:left;
width:100%;
position: relative;
}


#myWrapper{
overflow: hidden;
visibility: visible;
width: 620px;
}
```